# Adding a new style to the element results in error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to add a new style to an object and I'm getting this error:

> NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document

Code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var buttonComputedStyles = getComputedStyle(button);

buttonComputedStyles.setProperty("animation", targetAnimation); // error here
```

Is it not possible to make edits to the computed style declaration?

What is the recommended place to add styles?

```
 button.style.setProperty("animation", value);
```

**UPDATE**:
OK the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) linked from @jmargolisvt says:

> The returned style is a live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates
>   automatically when the element's styles are changed.

"The returned style is a live object" - I read that a while ago and that's what had confused me.

Comment: That's correct, it's not possible.  It's read-only.  Your answer is in the MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: `button.setProperty("animation", targetAnimation);` although I'm not entirely sure what you're after

Comment: @j08691 I'd imagine OP wants to set the CSS property, not a property on the button itself. To OP - what is wrong with your last line of code?

Comment: @TylerRoper It works doing that but I had thought I could modify the computed style object. I'll see if I can find the documentation where it says that.

Comment: @TylerRoper `button.style.animation =  targetAnimation;`?

Comment: @j08691 Yeah that'd do it. I just meant that the line of code in your previous comment didn't seem to align with the goal.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Right. That's the doc I read a while ago. One line confused me. I've updated the answer post. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)...

> The returned style is a live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates
> automatically when the element's styles are changed.
> The returned object is the same CSSStyleDeclaration type as the object
> returned from the element's style property. However, the two objects
> have different purposes:
>
> The object from getComputedStyle is ***read-only***, and should be used to
> inspect the element's style — including those set by a  element
> or an external stylesheet.
>
> The element.style object should be used to
> set styles on that element, or inspect styles directly added to it
> from JavaScript manipulation or the global style attribute.