I am getting an error when using setProperty method in javascript trying to modifying a css element value
I am getting an error when using setProperty method in javascript trying to modify a css element value using Setproperty method.
As seen setproperty method is a CSSStyleDeclaration Object Methods and should work with below code.
but is giving me error as below

css.html:20 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'color' property is read-only.



function click1() {
  var para      = document.querySelector('h1');
  var parameter = window.getComputedStyle(para);
  var d         = parameter.getPropertyValue('color');
  document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = d;
  parameter.setProperty('color', 'red');
}
h1 {
  color: rgb(77, 50, 130);
}
<h1 id="a">My First CSS Example</h1>
<button onclick="click1()">HTML</button>




https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457623/4935162

You're setting the innerHTML to the get property value, that doesn't make sense.

@Yogi Oh, my bad. But then an easy para.style.color = 'red' would do it.

@deEr. as I wrote in my previous comment[deleted], and to be more precise, CSS written in <style> tags or even on a linked .css file are read-only (as stated in the post error). However, you can change this color property by adding a CSS class, or directly here on the HTML tag using JS: para.style.setProperty('color', 'red');. Which will change the HTML to <h1 id="a" style="color: red;">...

@MisterJojo Got you. Just thought you meant the color property is seen as read-only when using setProperty(). I stand corrected again.

I see that you want to change the color of parameter. It doesn't work because you cannot change the color of objects that you change using getPropertyValue. To do that you have to use this: para.style.color = 'red;' 

@Mateuszprogrammer1302 you mean getComputedStyle() ?

@MisterJojo yes sorry for my mistake

The CSSStyleDeclaration returned from getComputedStyle() is computed by taking all the styles applied through various means (inline, stylesheets) into account.
But you can access the inline CSSStyleDeclaration like this:
para.style.color = "red";

or like this:
para.style.setProperty("color", "red");

